# Centre of Mass calculations - how to choose strips?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, coordinate-systems

I am a bit confused about how to determine which strips to consider when calculating the $\text{COM}$ of certain objects.

For example, when we calculate the $\text{COM}$ of a semi circle solid of radius $R$, we usually orientate it about the $x$ axis with the $\text{COM}$ on the $x$ axis.

Strips are then chosen to go vertically down the semi circle. Why? Why don't we choose it going horizontally for example?

Comment: The short answer is you can chose whatever strips you desire as long as you can take the integrals. At the end of the day you are taking a multiple integral. Perhaps, symmetries in the problem, make the calculations **easier** in some cases than the others.

Comment: @Ali why does taking them vertically make the integral easier?

Comment: It doesn't make it easier for a circle really (since it's the same either way).  The difference will have to do with how things work out in terms of using x values or y values.

Answer (score 0):

Well, as Ali said in the comment, there really isn't a general preference in choosing "stripes". We usually chose which equation is easier to integrate.
 For example an object like in the figure below might be represented by an equation like $y = 4-x^2$.
[image: Graph of $y = 4-x^2]And choosing to use vertical stripes and integrating y with x is going to be easier than using horizontal stripes.
  As in the case of a uniform circular disc, both choices are equally straightforward. Maybe the reason vertical stripes were used is because we usually integrate y over x.